# Find lists from multiple collections in clojure

Tags: collections, clojure, combinations

I am a newbie to clojure. One question I am facing is to find special lists from multiple collections.

1. list one: (1 2 3 4 5)
2. list two: (a b c d e f)

Source list: (1 c 2 b 4 e a f)
Lists to find in the source list: (a 1), (1 a), (4 c), (f 2)

How to resolve it?
Thanks

Comment: How does the *source list* determine the *special combinations*? Another example or two might help.

Comment: The source list happens to contain items from both list one and two. It may contains none from list one or two. The combinations are not determined by the source list. They are pre-defined. But one combination has to contain one from list one and the other from list two. The goal is to search for each combination in the source list. It is not about to find all the possible combinations from both list. So another set of combinations can be (1 f), (2 e), (3 c), (4 b).  Combination may not be the proper word. It is just a list of two items.

Comment: "each combination in the source list" so you want permutations?
`=> (combo/permutations [1 1 2])
([1 1 2] [1 2 1] [2 1 1])
`

Comment: @nha. Thanks for your answer below. I am really looking to search 2-item list in a big source list. The 2 items are determined by the list one and two. Your answer achieves the first leg and then I will iterate over the results to intersect with the source list.

Comment: @hnsyqz I don't quite get what you want to be honest. As requested, posting more examples would help.

Comment: Again sorry for the confusion. The answer given below by @rmcv is exactly what I am looking for. One example is :

Comment: @hnsyqz Then you should accept his answer by clicking tick mark next to his answer (make it green).

Comment: @nha, thanks. I tried that but since I just joined stackoverflow I don't have 15 reputations to do it. But my acceptance is recorded according to the message I got. :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics

```
=> (combo/cartesian-product [1 2] [3 4])
((1 3) (1 4) (2 3) (2 4))
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. it's not about to find the combinations from two lists. Please check the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of the problem is correct and you don't mind brute-force, you can use this solution.

```
(let [list1  '#{1 2 3 4 5}
      list2  '#{a b c d e f}
      source '(1 c 2 b 4 e a f)]
  (for [x     source
        y     source
        :when (or (and (list1 x) (list2 y))
                  (and (list1 y) (list2 x)))]
    [x y]))
```

=>

([1 c] [1 b] [1 e] [1 a] [1 f] [c 1] [c 2] [c 4] [2 c] [2 b] [2 e] [2 a] [2 f] [b 1] [b 2] [b 4] [4 c] [4 b] [4 e] [4 a] [4 f] [e 1] [e 2] [e 4] [a 1] [a 2] [a 4] [f 1] [f 2] [f 4])

You can also use shuffle to introduce some randomness and use take n to acquire the samples you need.

Or to make it even simpler, just remove items from list1 and list2 not in source and loop through these filtered lists.

Comment: Great idea! I will give a try to the simpler solution too.